# Mongo array update or push in one query

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Let's assume we have mongo collection containing documents of the following shape:

```
 {
   _id: '1234',
   letters: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
 }
```

but sometimes the `letters` field may be `null`.

**I am wondering if it is possible to achieve the following in a SINGLE query**

- If `letters` array is non empty, set the first item to 'x'.
- Otherwise, set `letters` field to `['x']`.

Of course, the simplest possible idea does not work

```
db.collection.update({_id: '...'}, {$set:{'letters.0':'x'}});
```

because if the `letters` field was not yet set the result of the above operation will be:

```
{
  // ...
  letters: {
    '0': 'x'
  }
}
```

Is there some way to tell mongo that my intention is to create an array, not an object?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [$push](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) operator, or the [$addToSet](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) if you care for duplicates on the array.

Your query will look like this:

```
db.collection.update({_id: '...'}, {$push:{'letters':'x'}});
db.collection.update({_id: '...'}, {$addToSet:{'letters':'x'}});
```

Comment: Sure, but I guess it would not work if I already have a couple of elements there and I only want to update the first one.

Comment: Oh, now i get your question, you want to update the specified position, or create the array. That's why you put the $set operator on your question. Looking at the docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update-array/ I could not find the operator for that, the $ -
 https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional mentions "Do not use the positional operator $ with upsert operations because inserts will use the $ as a field name in the inserted document.". It's the same behaviour that you described, so I think you cannot do that with a single command.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update the first one in the array

pop out the old first one

```
db.collection.update({_id:xx}, {$pop:{letters : -1}})
```

Then push to the first one

```
db.collection.update({_id:xx}, {$push:{letters : {$each:['first one'], $position:0}}})
```