# Best practice to store and update Time-series data in an mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb

I am using mongodb to store the data of a sensor. Sensor pushes the data via mqtt, and nodejs (loopback) is being used to persist data in mongodb. 
following properties are required to be saved in a document.

```
{
  "time": "2019-01-01T14:22:55.691Z",
  "value1": 0,
  "value2":50 (but value2 will be received after few minutes of value1)
}
```

Story: I am using ultrasonic sensor to check the water level in tank. when I turn on the water pump I save the value of water level as value1 and when I turn off the water pump I want to save it as value2, as there will be many documents so how I can update a document for value2? do I query the latest "time" property or any other better way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mongo array update or push in one query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43260267/mongo-array-update-or-push-in-one-query)

Comment: The data you are storing is usually referred to as Time Series and there are many resources online, eg: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/time-series-data-and-mongodb-part-1-introduction

Comment: Thanks @Cristy, Term Time Series helped me.